# appending dictionary to master list

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

For some reason it's not letting me add a string item to a key in a dictionary.

Here is my code:

example of  `splitUserList(line)`:

```
>>> splitUserList("1|24|M|technician|85711    ")
['1', 24, 'M', 'technician', '85711']
```

Code:

```
def createUserList():
    userList = []
    totalUserList = []
    f = open("u.user.txt")
    for line in f:
        userDict = {}
        singleUserList = splitUserList(line)
        userDict["age"] = singleUserList[1]
        userDict["gender"]  = singleUserList[2]
        userDict["occupation"] = singleUserList[3]
        singleUserList["zip"] = singleUserList[4]
        userList.append(userDict)
    return userList
```

Why is it not working?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 20, in createUserList    
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you meant

```
userDict["zip"] = singleUserList[4]
```

instead of

```
singleUserList["zip"] = singleUserList[4]  # <-- singleUserList is a list, 
                                           #     and you cannot index it via a string
```